# Ajax/php header:Location

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal with an Ajax login form.
Displaying errors and everything works just fine until the result from **login.php** is  `header('Location: index.php');`

I handle the result like this:

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the login is successful and I get the `header('Location: index.php');` response **index.php** is opened in `div.status`.

Is there an easy way to translate the PHP header to a redirect in javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect if the request is an ajax request. If it is return a json object that has the desired location otherwise do a typical php redirect.

```
<?php   
    function isAjax() {
        return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
    }

    if(isAjax()) {
        echo json_encode(array("location" => "index.php"));
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Once you get the json object back in javascript redirect the user using

```
document.location = json.location;
```

Comment: Using headers in AJAX is not secure. It can be faked. I suggest using something that only server-side language can process, such as `$_POST`

Comment: @WebDegBrian The code is written to avoid giving headers for ajax requests. Not sure what your concern is here but $_POST can also be "faked".

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to rewrite the `document.location` instead of sending a HTTP header.  It will give the user the same basic experience as a traditional redirect response from a full page request.

Comment: Allright, is there any function I can use or should I just send numbers from php and handle errors based on that in js? I'm new to php.

Comment: I would use a JSON object - see json_encode, so you could return an object something like { success: true, location: "http://www.example.com" }. Then on the js side, you could just redirect to the location property of the result object. You'll also need to look at JSON.parse for the JS side to get JSON from the text that's returned.

Comment: The text for the errors is a simple echo '<div>some text</div>'. How will it handle that after the json thing is done? My knowledge of json is 0.

Comment: You should probably respond with HTML markup that includes a `<script>` tag to do your javascript work.  Or, you can refactor the process.

Comment: ah- well there's no better time to learn than now. In the answer above, use something like:

`if ($success) {
   echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "location" => "index.php"));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "There was an error in logging in"));
}`

Then on the JS side you can check if result.success is true and if not, display result.message. Learning how to do this now will make a huge difference in the code you write from now on.